# Error opening `routes` file in Scala IDE

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1, scala-ide

I am working with my first scala-play2 framework application ( hello world ). It is working fine. But after importing the project in eclipse I tried opening `routes` file. All I got was this:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "org.scala-ide.play2" was unable to instantiate class "org.scalaide.play2.routeeditor.RouteEditor".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:283)
```

So, as of of now I am opening `routes` file in normal text editor. 
Please let me know how can I open this file in RouteEditor.

Comment: More information are needed, like the version numbers of Eclipse, Scala IDE and the Play support plugin. Also the stack trace doesn't have the interesting information. There should be a 'caused by', or an other stacktrace around it.

Comment: My bad, I was using bastardized version of eclipse. I have Juno and I was using scala-ide for eclipse 3.8 and Play framework for 3.7. Don't know why it didn't said anything while installing. I uninstalled these plugin, and install plugins for 3.8. It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17579904/error-opening-routes-file-in-scala-ide#comment25613062_17579904), you had installed the play plugin for Eclipse Indigo, running on Eclipse Juno. To avoid that kind of problem, select very carefully the correct update-site on the Scala-IDE [download page](http://scala-ide.org/download/current.html), and then only compatible plugins will be suggested for you.